# Collecting subsequences from a sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence

Let’s say we have the following sequence:

```
[1, 2, 1, 1]
```

We want to compute all the subsequences from this given sequence according to the following rule:

```
if s_i <= s_i+1 then s_i+1 is part of a subsequence with s_i
```

A subsequence is computed by starting with the first element of a sequence, here `1`, and comparing it to it’s right neighbor, here `2`. If they apply to the condition the form a subsequence. Afterwards, `2` must be compared to its right neighbor `1` and if they apply, it joins the subsequence. Here they don’t so it doesn’t join.

This process continues with `2` and the neighbor of the previous neighbor `1` until the end of the sequence. Afterwards, the process continues with the neighbor of `2` in the similar manner.

The following graph shows the subsequence building process for the first element `1` in the sequence:

[image: Algorithm]

Hence, the problem is recursive in nature. Here is the code:

```
def calc(seq):
    for i in range(0, len(seq)):
          calc_subseq(i, seq)

def calc_subseq(i, seq):
       a = seq[i]
       for j in range(i+1, len(seq):
           b[j] = seq[j]
           if b <= a:
               calc_subseq(j, seq);
           else:
                #build subsequence
        #build subsequnce
```

The question is now:

How to retrieve the subsequences after calculating them? I’ve used a stack and passed it with every call. Additionally, I’ve passed a counter which gets increased with every match and passed with every function call and also returned afterwards. In case of a mismatch i pop as much items from the stack as the counter counts. I do the same when the end of the for loop is reached in `calc_subseq(seq)`. But I’m looking for a better solution.

Does anyone know of any algorithm to solve similar problems? It would be quite interesting if there is a more efficient way. I thought about some sort of dynamic programming.

**Edit:**

As requested, here are all the results for the input sequence `[1,2,1,1]`:

```
1 (0), 2 (1)
2 (1)
2 (1)
2 (1) -> end
1 (0), 1 (2), 1 (3) 
1 (3) -> end
1 (2) -> end 
1 (0), 1(3)
1 (3) -> end
1 (0) -> end
2 (1)
2 (1)
2 (1) -> end
1 (2), 1 (3)
1 (3) -> end
1 (2) -> end
1 (3) -> end
```

**Note:** The indexes are provided as `(x)`. `-> end` indicates that the end of the second for loop was reached. Hence, it shows the last element which couldn't be compared because there was no neighbor left.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like finding "monotonic sequences". [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17000300/9225671) has some ideas for that

Comment: So how should the result from `[1, 2, 1, 1]` look like? I must say I'm not sure I understand the algorithm as you've described it. Also, can you add more examples and what result do you expect? (like 2 or 3 is enough).

Comment: Sure, I’ve added the results for the first element (1) in the sequence.

Comment: I don't see how you get `[1, 1, 1]` subsequence - as I understood the explanation, I thought you would get only `[1], [1, 2], [2], [1], [1, 1]`..

Comment: My explanation is quite complicated I guess. I find it quite hard to explain it with words. I’ll change that later and probably add a picture so it’s easier. The thing here is, that every element is compared to all it’s neighbors. If a match occurs, the process continues with the matching element. That’s why I need the recursion.

Comment: So your goal is to find all of the rising subsequences?  If there are multiple ways to get a subsequence, do you just want it once?  That is, in your example you can get the subsequence `1, 1` in 3 ways.  Do you want to count it once, or once each for `0,2`, `0,3` AND `2,3`?

Comment: I’m really just interested in unique ones. I’m not interested in the rising but the sequences of elements that share a certain relationship. Here it’s <=.

Comment: @Bastian For your example results, why don't you have the sub-sequence `(2,)`?

Comment: @Bastian If you add more examples, maybe you won't have to describe the algorithm and we will be able to derive it from examples (also, this means I could write unittests with these examples).

Comment: I have. This are just some examples. (2 ,)is smaller than the second and the third 1 so I have it at least 2 times.

Comment: @Bastian Are the provided results only s subset of the full set of results? You should give all the results for the expected input, not just a few examples.

Comment: There would be quite a lot to post here even with this small sequence. @JanSpurny requested only a few ones so I posted only a subset.

Comment: @Bastian I see. I think you need to write ALL of them if we are to understand the algorithm. Or you can write the tests and put them in the question - like: `assert getsubseq([1, 2, 1, 1]) == [[1, 2], [2], [2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1]]`

Comment: Allright. I’ll post all of them when I’ve access to a computer in a couple of hours.

Comment: @Bastian I think it would be good to post these sub-sequences together with indices like `1(0), 2(1)` for example (indices in parentheses). Or just post the indices of sub-sequences, the values can then be retrieved if desired. What is really important are the indices, since the original sequence contains duplicated items.

Comment: @a_guest He is just interested in unique values, therefore a given subsequence may have many sets of indexes that can be applied.

Comment: @btilly right! But I’ve added so I may be easier to understand the algorithm.

Comment: I've added all the results and a graph to explain the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a major problem.  If the original sequence has length `n`, the longest rising subsequence has expected length `O(sqrt(n))` and each subset of this sequence is another rising subsequence, so there are at least `O(exp(sqrt(n)))` of them. If `n` is even of moderate size, the number of such subsequences quickly gets very, very large.

I will therefore show you instead how to create a compact tree like structure from which you can calculate the count of rising subsequences in such a way that you can easily produce each answer in finite time.  I have not kept track of the indexes, but that feature will be easy to add if you want it:

```
def rising_tree (seq):
    tree = {}
    for item in reversed(seq):
        this_count = 1 # For the subsequence of just this item
        this_next = {}
        for next_item, data in tree.items():
            if item <= next_item:
                this_count = this_count + data[0]
                this_next[next_item] = data
        tree[item] = [this_count, this_next]
    total_count = 0
    for _, data in tree.items():
        total_count = total_count + data[0]
    return [total_count, tree]
```

When applied to your example of `[1, 2, 1, 1]` you get the following data structure:

```
[   5, # How many rising subsequences were found
    {   1: [   4, # How many start with 1
               {   1: [   2,  # How many start with 1, 1
                          {   1: [   1, # How many start with 1, 1, 1
                                     {   }]}],
                   2: [   1, # How many start with 1, 2
                          {   }]}],
        2: [   1, # How many start with 2
           {   }]}]
```

And now we can extract them all as follows:

```
def tree_sequence_iter (tree):
    items = sorted(tree[1].keys())
    for item in items:
        yield [item]
        subtree = tree[1][item]
        if (subtree[1]):
            for subseq in tree_sequence_iter(subtree):
                yield [item] + subseq


for ss in tree_sequence_iter(rising_tree([1, 2, 1, 1])):
    print(ss)
```

Do note that I didn't need the call to `sorted` that I slipped in there, but with that we not only get unique subsequences out, we actually get them in lexicographic order!  (Though do keep in mind that there can be a lot of them.)

And if you really don't want a generator (and think we have memory to store them), we can simply `list(tree_sequence_iter(rising_tree(seq)))` to generate our list.

Comment: Thank you very much! Let me think about it for a moment please.